# 502 Bad Gateway error Nginx and uWSGI in deploying Flask app

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

I'm trying to deploy a Flask app on a Linode VPS running Ubuntu 10.10. I've been following this tutorial (https://library.linode.com/web-servers/nginx/python-uwsgi/ubuntu-10.10-maverick#sph_configure-nginx) but I keep getting a 502 Bad Gateway error.

Here this is /etc/default/uwsgi:

```
PYTHONPATH=/var/www/reframeit-im
MODULE=wsgi
```

Here is /var/www/reframeit-im/wsgi.py:

```
# add the application directory to the python path
import sys
sys.path.append("/var/www/reframeit-im")

# run flask app
from reframeit import app as application
```

Here is the app's nginx config file, which is symlinked to the /sites-enabled directory (/opt/nginx/conf/sites-enabled/reframeit-im):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.reframeit-im.coshx.com reframeit-im.coshx.com;
    access_log /var/www/reframeit-im/logs/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/reframeit-im/logs/error.log;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
    }
}
```

I checked the nginx error logs for the app and I found this:

```
2013/07/17 19:30:19 [error] 20037#0: *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 70.88.168.82, server: www.reframeit-im.coshx.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:9001", host: "reframeit-im.coshx.com"
```

Is there something wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 1):

With `uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;` you declared to Nginx your intent to talk to uWSGI through TCP socket, but have not warned uWSGI about it.

Try adding a corresponding socket line to your `/etc/default/uwsgi` file:

```
PYTHONPATH=/var/www/reframeit-im
MODULE=wsgi
socket=127.0.0.1:9001
```

Comment: Adding the `socket` line doesn't seem to do anything; I still get the 502 Bad Gateway error.

Comment: still getting the `upstream prematurely closed connection` error? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Please add "protocol = uwsgi" apart from what Flavio has suggested. As below

```
PYTHONPATH=/var/www/reframeit-im
MODULE=wsgi
socket=127.0.0.1:9001
protocol = uwsgi
```